# Resize divs automatically to always fill screen (Flexbox)

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get a dynamic display of boxes, So that no matter how many boxes are displayed or what size the screen is, they will always take up the whole screen.

At the moment the first few boxes are small and the last boxes grow to fill that space. How can i make sure all boxesresize to always fill the screen and all always be the same size as each other.

I have tried using space around, stretch, center... what am i missing?
make sure you view the code in firefox or chrome.. cheers.

```css
.siteBox
{
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 flex: 1;
 

}
.siteBoxHolder
{
 margin: 20px;
 display:flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;

 
}
.siteBoxImage
{
 width: 100%;
}
.siteTitle
{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 <title>Custom Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="siteBoxHolder">
        

  <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

  

  

 </div>
 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly in that regardless of how many boxes there are you want them to fill up the screen *and* be exactly all the same size...then not even `flexbox` can do that. You'd need javascript and even then I'd think you'd have trouble. Of course, I'd love to be proved wrong.

Comment: bugger, i am so close with flexbox tho. theorectically flexbox should be able to do it? if there is 8 boxes 2 rows 4 so they fit perfectly, if there are 9 then they all shrink a little so 9 fits etc etc

Comment: No flexbox can't change basic math. If you want even rows and equal sizes then not every number will work. So numbers like 5, 7, 11,13 etc just aren't going to be divisible that way.

Comment: yeah i understand, I don't care about equal rows, just that they all take up the space on screen, so if it makes the top row 4 and the bottom 3 as long as the bottom 3 are centered it's fine. but thanks for your help regardless.

Comment: Oh...that I think we can do. - http://jsfiddle.net/nvbv2y45/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, But this is where I am at now, The last box is taking up the whole width, my only requirement is that all the boxes are the same size and it takes up the full screen. any ideas?

Comment: You **can't** do that if you have rows and a number of 'cells' that won't divide nicely for the reasons I mentioned above.  Perhaps you could make an image of what this is supposed to look like because I'm not quite sure what look you are going for.

Comment: hmm heres my lame attempts at examples. I don't mind what arrangement as long as all of them are same size and shrunk to fit basically.

So [two boxes](http://gyazo.com/9ebc5f77df90655091bdff82247f0940)

and [three boxes](http://gyazo.com/ba968a593bd61f69d9621d0b5f4edcba)
and [six boxes](http://gyazo.com/5855ae9ca4c1b4ab6530b134e5412066)
and you get the point [20 boxes](http://gyazo.com/82ad0e1bae9b4448276bbd937d844fd7)
and if we remove one [19](http://gyazo.com/1f43db056ce97ecf6061b9f5ef8b8a34)

just realised when i said take up the whole screen i might of caused the confusion sorry.

Comment: Oh...i see. No, I don't think so. I think you need to be able to specify at least one dimension (height or width) to allow `flexbox` to calculate the spacing.

Comment: That's ok, I have decided to just hard code some arrangements for now. Thanks for your help.